# SMB server not working after upgrade from 3.5 to 3.6

Tags: centos, samba

our Windows 7/2008 clients can't access our samba server any more after the upgrade to version 3.6.

This is on CentOS 6 (`rpm --query centos-release` reports `centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`).

This is what I can see from the samba logs:

```
[2016/04/18 15:11:53.564262,  0] auth/check_samsec.c:492(check_sam_security)
check_sam_security: make_server_info_sam() failed with 'NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL'
```

and this is my smb.conf file:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]

# ----------------------- Network Related Options -------------------------

    workgroup = WOLFPACK
    server string = Wolfpack Samba Server Version %v

    interfaces = lo 10.0.0.0/16 129.94.136.0/25 192.168.11.0/24
    hosts allow = 127. 10.0. 129.94. 192.168. 149.171.

    map untrusted to domain = yes

# --------------------------- Logging Options -----------------------------

    # logs split per machine
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
    max log size = 50

# ----------------------- Standalone Server Options ------------------------

#       security = user
#       passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYY
#       ldap suffix =  dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX
#       ldap suffix =
#       ldap user suffix = ou=People
#       ldap group suffix = ou=Group
#       ldap admin dn = cn=XXX,ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX
#       ldap ssl = no
#       ldap passwd sync = no
#       ldap delete dn = no

#       deadtime = 10

    idmap config * : backend      = ldap
    idmap config * : range        = 1000000-1999999
    idmap config * : ldap_url     = ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYY
    idmap config * : ldap_base_dn = cn=XXX,ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX
    idmap config * : ldap_user_dn = cn=XXX,ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================

[temp]
    comment = PanFS temp vol via smb
    path = /directflow/Temp
    public = no
    valid users = XXXX
    writable = yes
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0644
    force create mode = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    force directory mode = 0755
    share modes = yes

[runs]
    comment = PanFS RUNS vol via smb
    path = /directflow/RUNS
    public = no
    valid users = XXXXX
    write list = user1
    writable = no
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0644
    force create mode = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    force directory mode = 0755
    share modes = yes

[tmp]
    comment = Server local tmp via smb
    path = /tmp
    public = no
    valid users = XXXXX
    write list = user1
    writable = no
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0644
    force create mode = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    force directory mode = 0755
    share modes = yes
```

This is what I get when I run `net getdomainsid` command

```
Failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
Unable to open secrets.tdb.  Can't fetch domain SID for name: XXXX
```

EDIT: more info

```
pwbcad@r815:~$ pdbedit -L
tdbsam_open: Failed to open/create TDB passwd [/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb]
tdbsam_getsampwnam: failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb!
User Search failed!
```

and

```
$ smbclient -U USER \\\\localhost\\<username>
Enter USER's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

running `/usr/bin/smbpasswd -w ldap_pwd` did not help

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you `diff` the original config and the newly upgraded config?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Even 3.6 was EOL a while ago so I would like to assume you're using a vendor's LTS version that's being back-patched. As a result it would be worth (re)visiting the "what's changed" between your vendor's 3.5 and 3.6.

Comment: @roaima pwbcad@r815:~$ rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64
I am using a plain CentOS version

Comment: @EightBitTony our samba server stopped working after the upgrade, I haven't changed the configuration file at all

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros depending on what you used to update the product, the package manager may have updated the config file.  That's why I asked.  What does `stat /var/lib/samba/private` and `stat /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb` return?  Please add the output to the question, not as a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: btw: I note you put xxx for the LDAP suffix, but you left more than enough info to identify where the file relates to (IP address, dn =), not sure if you intended that.

Comment: Is your `secrets.tdb` actually in `/var/lib/samba/private`? I recall a Debian update not so long ago that moved the `secrets.tdb` file and for some reason or other mine didn't get moved automatically during the update process.

Comment: @roaima yes, private is in /var/lib/samba/private thanks

Comment: Please disable selinux temporarily. If that works I'll post a proper answer.